# Devolver valor de una función en Python

Tags: python

Estoy empezando en Python y tengo problemas en que no me da el resultado del def
no sé como hacer para que me de el resultado.
La estructura es la siguiente:

```
fuerza = input("indique la fuerza: ")
masa = input("indique la masa: ")
aceleracion = input("indique la aceleración: ")
def calculo (fuerza, masa, aceleracion):
if fuerza == "":
    fuerza=None
else:
    fuerza=int(fuerza)
if masa == "":
    masa=None
else:
    masa=int(masa)
if aceleracion=="":
    aceleracion=None
else:
    aceleracion=int(aceleracion)
if fuerza and masa and not aceleracion:
    resultado=fuerza/masa
elif masa and aceleracion and not fuerza:
    resultado=masa/aceleracion
elif fuerza and aceleracion and not masa:
    resultado = fuerza / aceleracion
print(calculo)
```

He intentado poner el print fuera de la función y cosas similares, si alguien pudiese ayudarme se lo agradecería muchísimo.

Comment: Tienes problemas de indentación, por otro lado, tu función no devuelve nada (te faltaría una sentencia `return resultado`), el resultado de tu función podrías asignarlo a una variable: `res = calculo(...)`. Por útlimo, el `print(calculo)` no va a ejecutar la función.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si ese es tu código, tiene varios problemas:

1. El indentado, todo el código de dentro de la función tiene que estar indentado un nivel más que la definición de la función.
2. Para devolver un valor, necesitas usar la expresión `return <nombre_variable`. En este caso, `return resultado` al final de la función.
3. Para llamar a la función, tienes que pasar las variables, en este caso: `calculo(fuerza, masa, aceleracion).
4. Deberías inicializar la variable `resultado` a algo, por si no entra en ninguna rama del `if/else`, evitas que el programa de error.

Teniendo todo esto en cuenta, tu código sería más bien así:

```py
fuerza = input("indique la fuerza: ")
masa = input("indique la masa: ")
aceleracion = input("indique la aceleración: ")

def calculo(fuerza, masa, aceleracion):
  if fuerza == "":
    fuerza = None
  else:
    fuerza = int(fuerza)
  if masa == "":
    masa = None
  else:
    masa = int(masa)

  if aceleracion == "":
    aceleracion = None
  else:
    aceleracion = int(aceleracion)

  resultado = None
  if fuerza and masa and not aceleracion:
    resultado = fuerza / masa
  elif masa and aceleracion and not fuerza:
    resultado = masa / aceleracion
  elif fuerza and aceleracion and not masa:
    resultado = fuerza / aceleracion

  return resultado

print(calculo(fuerza, masa, aceleracion))
```

Comment: Tal como está tu código, no imprime el resultado, sólo imprime `None`, ya que tu función carece de una sentencia `return resultado`. Corrige tu respuesta. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras bargh! Gracias! Ya está.